# Can we git undo committed files from the folder towards the destination branch?

Tags: git, git-revert

Due to pre-commit hooks configured for lint, accidentally committed some unwanted files which just has alignment fixes towards destination branch.

This has changed a lot of files majorly `.json` files, can we revert the file change. We noticed these changes bit later, so hence we can't even ammend now. Is there any chance to undo this file changes especially `.json` inside some folders towards the destination branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say PR is raised from Branch "A" to branch "B"

You can replace the folder in your local workspace from branch B doing the following

git checkout B com/test/src/main/resources

Then do a git add and git push origin to branch A.

After the above steps you will not see the files under resources in the PR diff anymore

Answer (score 0):

If the commit cannot be amended because of additional commits being made, [it can be interactively rebased](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

However, if the affected commits have already been pushed, this may be a difficult task to do, due to synchronization issues if other developers have pulled the affected branch and have done changes on top of the commits that have been modified.